# Javascript split working incorrectly in IE

Tags: prestashop

I have one page checkout. My OPC works fine with other browsers but I get a fatal error with IE. IE's Javascript console says `Object doesn't support this property or method.`. The method in question is `var items = field_name.split(reg)` from the file: `order-address.tpl`.

I have no idea what is causing the problem. Because of this error, I cannot login properly from one page checkout when using IE. It seems that there are a lot of people with the same problem. What's the issue?

This error is present in 1.4.9, 1.4.10, and 1.5.3.

Comment: With more than 3 years of PS experience i myself never fixed such issues with IE. But at one of my last site, i was having some JS issues with IE, and i found that IE was loading some JS files even all other browsers were loading them correctly. I am not sure, but please check that JQuery, and other related JS files are all loaded in IE or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. It turns out the issue is not with coding but with settings of IE.
All I had to do was reset IE from Tools => internet options => advanced => reset (including personal settings)
That did it for me. Thank you altafhussain for trying to help me out.